# XML: Gain Data with LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing

So, I started this project, and I dunno how to even search for it.

I have this very simple XML file:

```
version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<AI>
  <ai>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>NAME</name>
    ...
  </ai>
</AI>
```

I want to search for "name" elements get the "id" element for result. I tried lot of ways, most of them wrote something weirdo...

Comment: There are many examples on stackoverflow that show you how to parse xml with link to xml. search first before posting. Btw post what you tried so we can correct you.

Comment: I Tried Xpath now, doesn't seem working, some weird looking code, eg. var n = doc.Root.Elements().Select(x=>x.Element("id");

Comment: like I said search stackoverflow on how to use line to xml.  I have answer Andre question on using XElement.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/linq-to-xml/info

Answer (score 0):

I extended your example to include more `<ai>` tags so the results are clearer.

So first I convert the xml into `XElement`. If you are using file you can parse the whole file using `XDocument` instead. Next, I go down to the `<ai>` node and extract its content to an anonymous type. Then, when you have the content extracted it's easy to search through it with simple LINQ expression. In the example below I am returning `id` where the `name` is equal to `"NAME"`:

```
class Program
{
    // A sample xml string.
    static string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
                    <AI>
                      <ai>
                        <id>1</id>
                        <name>NAME</name>
                      </ai>
                      <ai>
                        <id>2</id>
                        <name>NAME2</name>
                      </ai>
                      <ai>
                        <id>3</id>
                        <name>NAME3</name>
                      </ai>
                    </AI>";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Read the string.
        XElement xelem = XElement.Parse(xml);

        var results = xelem.Descendants("ai")    // Get all <ai> nodes.
                           .Select(x =>
                           new
                           {
                               // Get values from <id> and <name>.
                               // Use anonymous types to store the results.
                               id = x.Descendants("id").First().Value,       
                               name = x.Descendants("name").First().Value,    
                           });

        // Filter out required result.
        var filtered = results.Where(x => x.name == "NAME").First().id;
    }
}
```